# Divide a string into sections in Angular

Tags: html, angular, split

I have a string of numbers (like an account number) that needs to be separated into smaller segments with a space in between (for example, 2 digits, 4 digits, 7 digits, 2 digits) and I cannot get this to display on the page. This is a generated number, so there is no user input. I need the number that comes back to be split into sections.  I am using Angular/Html.

For example, currently an "account number" might display as 123456765456712 & I need it to display 12 3456 7654567 12.

Comment: What have you tried? A custom pipe for formating input according to your rules of display seems like a straightforward thingbto do.

Comment: To have the expected output you need to create custom Pipe that will transform the UI.
Looks like an IBAN number.

Answer (score 3):

You could create custom pipe that implements `PipeTransform` and use this code there (of course it should be a bit adjusted).

```js
const accNo ="123456765456712";
const matched = accNo.match("(\\d{2})(\\d{4})(\\d{7})(\\d{2})");
matched.shift();
const formatted = matched.join(" ");
console.log(formatted);
```

You can run and see the output in console.

Please, mark it as an answer if it fixes your issue :)